# How do I throw an exception showing the calling line?

Tags: powershell

When I purposely throw an exception the stack trace shows the code that decided to throw the exception.

```
Example error message!!
At C:\path\to\script.ps1:101 char:37
+         else                            { throw $message; }
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Example error message!!:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Example error message!!
```

Is there a way in PowerShell that I can have it show the line that *called* my code. Because it is a problem with the calling code, not the throw line.

Comment: https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/, search for `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`. It describes this exact situation. I'm not in a position to write up an example.

Comment: `$Error[0].ScriptStackTrace` might be of use